# SQLite db duplicate values Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I'm using a `spinner` in my application that takes the values from a SQLite database. The problem is that every time I run the application from Eclipse the values loads again and again. So if the first time I have 5 values in the `spinner`, the second time I have 10 values, then 15, then 20 etc. How can I solve this?

This is the db part:

In the `onCreate`:

```
createTable();
        insertIntoTable();

        ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        my_array = getTableValues();

        My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.scelte);
        My_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, my_array);
        My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
```

and then:

```
// CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    public void createTable() {
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE
                    + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
            mydb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore durante la creazione della tabella",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION INSERTS DATA TO THE DATABASE
    public void insertIntoTable() {
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Cibo e Bevande','cibo')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Trasporti','trasporti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Svago','svago')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Acquisti vari','acquisti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Sanità','sanità')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Altro','altro')");
            mydb.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION SHOWS DATA FROM THE DATABASE
    public ArrayList<String> getTableValues() {

        ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor allrows = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);
            System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows.getCount());

            if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String ID = allrows.getString(0);
                    String NAME = allrows.getString(1);
                    String PLACE = allrows.getString(2);
                    my_array.add(NAME);


                } while (allrows.moveToNext());
            }
            allrows.close();
            mydb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        return my_array;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String selecteditem = My_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        TextView categorietext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sceltelabel);
        categorietext.setText(selecteditem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Do the checking before inserting the data into the table. You can 1. query the DB, if it is empty then insert, or 2. use `SharedPreference` to indicate that the DB has been initialized or not.

Answer (score 2):

You run this

```
insertIntoTable();
```

every time in `onCreate` so it adds more and more data.

You should use extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and use `onCreate` method to create your database and initialise tables. See [Android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Comment: yes.. but if i remove this how can i insert the values only for the first time?

Comment: Check `SQLiteOpenHelper` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html. It has `onCreate` method where you can do this sort of initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you will open your activity `onCreate` method of activity will be invoke and in your `onCreate` method you are calling  `insertIntoTable();` which will insert new record every time.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run the app, `onCreate()` will be called, and thus `insertIntoTable()` will also be called. You have to add a checking before inserting the data. One of the way is to check whether the DB is empty or not before inserting the data.

```
public void insertIntoTable() {
    try {
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = mydb.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) {
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Cibo e Bevande','cibo')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
            + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Trasporti','trasporti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
            + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Svago','svago')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
            + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Acquisti vari','acquisti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
            + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Sanità','sanità')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
            + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Altro','altro')");
            mydb.close();
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: `The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, null, null, null, null, null)` :(

Comment: i added a `null`, now i try

Comment: Sorry for the typo! Glad it worked. If possible, please mark the answer when you think it's correct to indicate that the problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run yor application you call `insertintotable()` method, so its is happenning

to solve this:

check the table is empty or not . if it is empty then call `insertintotable()` method else dont